# AJAX request with Zend Form

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery, zend-form

How do I submit a Zend form using ajax request with jquery so that the page does not refresh? I've used ajaxLink with Zend but I don't see how I can use it with a form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if there exists any inbuild function for form ajax submit in zf.
But you can accomplish this normal way.

One way is to append js file

```
$this->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile('//path to you jquery form submit script')
```

In other way you can add form submitting function on `onLoad function`

```
$function = "//some jquery-ajax form submit script"

$this->jQuery()->addOnload($function)
```

Comment: once you get your JS hammered out you can make a view helper to add it automatically with just one line of code.